# 2019 ROS distribuition

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can anyone tell me what is the name of the next ROS distribuition that will release in May?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318230/2019-ros-distribuition/) by [joelsonmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/36927/joelsonmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can anyone tell me what is the name of the next ROS distribuition that will release in May?

Noetic Ninjemys (from [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-melodic-morenia-release/4871), search for "noetic").

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1